# Selenium Python - Unable to find an element, get stale element exception when using element locator

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

Scenario:
1.Login to a website using script and navigate to the Home page.
2. On the home page, click a link and navigate to a new page.
3. Then navigate back to the home page using the top navigation bar Home link.

I am using the POM ( Page object model) where all my locators are defined in one python module.

The following is my directory structure
1. Properties.py ( This is where I specify all the login credentials, web driver and base url).

2. Envsetup.py( This has setup and tear down methods)
3. Locators.py ( This contains the locators for each page under a Locator class)
4. Page objects( Under this directory I have HomePage.py for the home page that has methods under the Homepage class, each of these methods returns a specific web element locator using the Locator class)
5. test scripts( test_homepage.py), this is where I am extending my Envsetup class to run the tests.

When I try to navigate back to my Home page, I get a stale elementrefernce exception error.

test_homepage.py

```
class Home(EnvSetup):
    def test_HomePage(self):
        browser = self.browser
        browser.implicitly_wait(10)
        homepage = Home(browser)
        assert browser.title
        print('Running tests on ' + browser.title)
        if homepage.view_all_users().is_displayed(): # This method is defined in the Hompage module
                homepage.view_all_users().click()
        else:
            raise NoSuchElementException

        #browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="home"]').click() -----------> This works fine, takes me back to the Home page

    if homepage.nav_to_home().is_displayed(): ----------> I get a StaleElementException error
                homepage.nav_to_home().click()

 In the following case, I get 

webDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH, homepage.nav_to_home()))
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given


        try:
            WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH, homepage.nav_to_home()))
        except StaleElementReferenceException as e:
            raise e

        homepage.nav_to_home().click()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Homepage.py

```
from Tests.Pageobjects.Locators import Locator
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
class Home(object):

    def __init__(self, browser):
        self.browser = browser
        self.logo = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, Locator.logo)
        self.nav_Home = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, Locator.nav_Home)

    def get_logo(self):
        return self.logo

    def nav_to_home(self):
        return self.nav_Home
```

Comment: I need to create a try except block or a for loop to avoid this exception?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the Stale element exception with used WebDriverwait in my Page object. 
Added `WebDriverwait(self.browser, 100).until(lambda browser: self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH, Locator.nav_Home)` to my methods that return the locators in the page object.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from WFC_POM.locators.locators import locators

class signup_page():

    def __int__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
        self.signin_button = locators.signin_button
        self.click_signup_button_xpath = locators.click_signup_button_xpath
        self.input_fullname_id = locators.input_Fullname_id
        self.input_username_id = locators.input_username_id
        self.input_mobile_id = locators.input_mobile_id
        self.input_email_id = locators.input_email_id
        self.input_dob_xpath = locators.input_dob_xpath
        self.input_gender_id = locators.input_gender_id
        self.input_address_id = locators.input_address_id

    def enter_signin_button(self):
        self.driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, self.signin_button).click()

    def click_signup_button(self):
        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, self.click_signup_button_xpath).click()

    def input_fullname(self, fullname):
        self.driver.find_element(By.ID, self.input_fullname_id).send_keys(fullname)

    def input_username(self, username):
        self.driver.find_element(By.ID, self.input_username_id).send_keys(username)
```